# What does "Mustn't've" mean?

Tags: contractions

This word is pretty confusing to me.
Please explain.
Does it mean must not have?

Comment: As you say, it is a contraction for "must not have."

Comment: It even has its own [entry in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mustn't've)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a double contraction - the *must* is contracted with both *not* (giving us *mustn't*) and *have* (giving us *must've*). If you do both, you get *mustn't've*

This is, however, very informal, especially in writing.

Comment: On top of being informal, it is very bad form.

Comment: It's pretty common in spoken English, indeed that is probably the source. So to use it to represent spoken language is not bad form at all.

Other similar forms, such as _can't've_ are even more common

Answer (score 0):

"Must not have", as you correctly say.